# Typeahead need to press enter,

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am very new to anguler js.when i search something a dropdown appears and after clicking the dropdown list i have to again press enter to work

```
    <div class="input-append input-group" style="padding-right: 25px;width: 100%;">
        <input id="inputActionTextBox" type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected"
               typeahead="action as action for action in getActionNames($viewValue)"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="Search by Action Name or Description"
               ng-enter="stepInputEnterPressed('fromNameSearch')" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}"  
               ng-keyup="keyPress($event.keyCode, $viewValue)" ng-dblclick="changeHandler()"
               style="font-style:italic; outline: none; width: 100%;"/>
    </div>
```

basicaly i need to call this function when user click any of the dropdown list `stepInputEnterPressed('fromNameSearch')`

Comment: Did you try ng-change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using **ng-click** instead of **ng-dblclick**.